# What is the default timeout for Cookie in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Cookie is a executable program, which the server posts to client machines but what is the timeout of the cookie

Learning the concept of cookies so this question comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET Core by default cookie set with `Append(string, string)` or `Append(String, String, CookieOptions)` with default options will result in so called session cookie which will expire once you log off or close the browser.

```cs
app.MapGet("/api/ttt", (HttpResponse resp) =>
{
    resp.Cookies.Append("testcookie", "val");
    resp.Cookies.Append("testcookie1", "val", new CookieOptions());
    return new { Test = "ok" };
});
```

You can control the cookie expiration by setting `MaxAge` or `Expires` properties on [`CookieOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookieoptions?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Note that ASP.NET Core has several specific cookies (like auth cookies) which can have their own default lifetimes.